# MySql on CloudFoundry often fails with Query execution was interrupted;

Tags: java, mysql, spring, cloud-foundry

I have a Spring MVC app with a MySQL DB on Cloud Foundry with about 1 million records.  Frequently it will throw SqlExceptions with the message "Query execution was interrupted".  It seems to throw this Exception pretty quickly.  Does anyone know what's causing this and how to resolve it?  As a side note, is there any way to get more than 128MB of DB space for a MySQL db on cloudfoundry?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like something you should be asking CloudFoundry customer support.

Comment: Good point Dan. Their [support page](http://support.cloudfoundry.com/home) directs people here but I'll ask them directly too and post any answers I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned from the Cloud Foundry support that they will kill any query that takes longer than 3 seconds, so the only resolution is to optimize your query (or break it up).  Also, there is no way to get more than 128MB of DB space for a MySQL db until they open up for paid use later this year / early next year.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for contacting cf support. Since you have both StackOverflow and the official CF support ticket opened, let us just update on the support ticket and keep track at this link: http://support.cloudfoundry.com/tickets/102525.

Thanks,
William