# Cloudfoundry: VMC: Error 1317: Query execution was interrupted on mysqldump

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry, vmc

It is quite important for me to dump the mysql database of my cloudfoundry deployment. I am working with cloudfoundry's vmc and connection to the service works well. However mysqldump always fails which puts me in an awful situation as I am essentially not able to dump the data to do local migration testing. 
The error presented by cloudfoundry / vmc is:

mysqldump: Error 1317: Query execution was interrupted when dumping table 'foo' at row: 28

It appears that this results from some setting in cloudfoundry that kills any query that takes longer than 3 seconds. See for instance

- [mysqldump: Error 1317: Query execution was interrupted while running database Backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021070/mysqldump-error-1317-query-execution-was-interrupted-while-running-database-ba)
- [MySql on CloudFoundry often fails with Query execution was interrupted;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065461/mysql-on-cloudfoundry-often-fails-with-query-execution-was-interrupted)

Is there anyway to change the configuration or make cloudfoundry ignore the 3 second rule for mysqldump? Any suggestions?

PS: This timeout has also shown to be very destructive if the execution of a migration takes to long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on the quality of the connection between yourself and CloudFoundry.com, these kind of timeouts can be an issue. It might be worth taking a look at a Ruby application I wrote to take routine backups of MySQL databases and upload them to a cloud service provider such as Amazon S3.

Take a look at the repository at https://github.com/danhigham/service_stash

The set up is pretty straight forward but if you get stuck then let me know.